# How to set width of mat-table column in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Here in my mat-table have 6 column when any column has not more words then it looks like Image-1, but when any column has more words then UI looks like Image-2, so how to set UI like Image-1 when any column has more words in angular 6 ?

Image-1

[image]

Image-2

[image]

user.component.html

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">      
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="userimage">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> # </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
      <img src="{{commonUrlObj.commonUrl}}/images/{{element.userimage}}" style="height: 40px;width: 40px;"/>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Full Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.username}} ( {{element.usertype}} )</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="emailid">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> EmailId </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.emailid}} </td>
   </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="contactno">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Contact No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.contactno}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="enabled">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Enabled </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="color: blue">
      <ng-container *ngIf="element.enabled == 'true'; else otherss">Enabled</ng-container>
        <ng-template #otherss>Disabled</ng-template>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxLayoutGap="5px">
        <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" routerLink="/base/editUserDetails/{{element.userid}}"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button>
        <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" routerLink="/base/viewUserDetails/{{element.userid}}"><mat-icon>pageview</mat-icon></button>
      </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 50 ,100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 183, accepted):

using css we can adjust specific column width which i put in below code.

user.component.css

```
table{
 width: 100%;
}

.mat-column-username {
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  white-space: unset !important;
  flex: 0 0 28% !important;
  width: 28% !important;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  word-break: break-word;

  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.mat-column-emailid {
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  white-space: unset !important;
  flex: 0 0 25% !important;
  width: 25% !important;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  word-break: break-word;

  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.mat-column-contactno {
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  white-space: unset !important;
  flex: 0 0 17% !important;
  width: 17% !important;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  word-break: break-word;

  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.mat-column-userimage {
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  white-space: unset !important;
  flex: 0 0 8% !important;
  width: 8% !important;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  word-break: break-word;

  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.mat-column-userActivity {
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  white-space: unset !important;
  flex: 0 0 10% !important;
  width: 10% !important;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  word-break: break-word;

  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

Comment: You should add which selector you add these classes to

Comment: @Nick: You are not going to add to any selector of the data table. Just name your css selector to be the same as the name you gave your matColumnDef in your .html file

Comment: @BashirM.Saad Thanks this makes things easier especially the selectors are predefined and no need to add custom selectors. It works exactly as shown.

Comment: why the `!important` ? Avoid this directive as much as possible as t's working fine without.

Comment: Is there a generic css class that I can use to all columns instead of repeating code for every column?

Answer (score 149):

As i have implemented, and it is working fine. you just need to add column width using `matColumnDef="description"`

for example :

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSortDisableClear>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="productId">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>product ID</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{product.id}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="productName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{product.name}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">
            <button (click)="view(product)">
                <mat-icon>visibility</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

here `matColumnDef` is
`productId`, `productName` and `action`

now we apply width by `matColumnDef`

styling

```
.mat-column-productId {
    flex: 0 0 10%;
}
.mat-column-productName {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

and remaining width is equally allocated to other columns

Comment: it works, just make sure you name your css class approapriately, for example .mat-column-xxx where xxx can by anything

Comment: Not really anything. Like he said, it should match the `matColumnDef`.

Comment: worked for me, too, but i used width instead of flex. thank you!

Answer (score 91):

If you're using scss for your styles you can use a mixin to help generate the code. Your styles will quickly get out of hand if you put all the properties every time.

This is a very simple example - really nothing more than a proof of concept, you can extend this with multiple properties and rules as needed.

```css
    @mixin mat-table-columns($columns)
    {
        .mat-column-
        {
            @each $colName, $props in $columns {
    
                $width: map-get($props, 'width');
                
                &#{$colName} 
                {
                    flex: $width;
                    min-width: $width;
    
                    @if map-has-key($props, 'color') 
                    {
                        color: map-get($props, 'color');
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in your component where your table is defined you just do this:

```css
    @include mat-table-columns((
    
        orderid: (width: 6rem, color: gray),
        date: (width: 9rem),
        items: (width: 20rem)
    
    ));
```

This generates something like this:

```css
    .mat-column-orderid[_ngcontent-c15] {
      flex: 6rem;
      min-width: 6rem;
      color: gray; }
    
    .mat-column-date[_ngcontent-c15] {
      flex: 9rem;
      min-width: 9rem; }
```

In this version `width` becomes `flex: value; min-width: value`.

For your specific example you could add `wrap: true` or something like that as a new parameter.

Comment: About time someone upvoted me for this :-) I've found this way very helpful - and you can extend it all you please as needed to be more consistent across components.

Comment: Note: You can of course use pixels if you prefer. I generally prefer ems when text data is involved, and I'm using rems here because when the header and cell font size is different they'll be skewed since by definition 'em' vary by font size.

Comment: This look super spiffy, but I'm unclear on where to put the mixin...

Comment: how to import `$columns` in mat-table ??

Comment: @SridharNatuva you don't import $columns, that's just a variable name in the defined mixin (look up sass mixins). When you use the mixin with @include that's where you put the value for $columns (in my example above `@include mat-table-columns((` the second parenthesis is beginning of the the value of $columns which is a sass data structure representing each named column)

Answer (score 74):

You can easily do this one. In each column you will get a class with the field name prefixed with mat-column, so the class will be like mat-column-yourFieldName. So for that you can set the style like following

```
.mat-column-yourFieldName {
    flex: none;
    width: 100px;
}
```

So we can give fixed width for column as per our requirement.

Hope this helps for someone.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you. what if I wanted to avoid to repeat `flex: none;` for each colum? let's say a class `.mat-column-* {
    flex: none;
}` i tried but it did not work.

Comment: @OJVM try using this syntax to target all columns in you scss.

`td, th { &[class*=" mat-column-"] { flex: none; } }`

Answer (score 38):

You can do it by using below CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th, td {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is a [`StackBlitz Example`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvdbmj-xngxgw) with Sample Data

Comment: It's about `mat-table` not `table[mat-table]`. This does not work for `mat-table` (flex). https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: not sure they say this does not work with mat-table, I have a mat table, set this code and works perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

Here's an alternative way of tackling the problem:

Instead of trying to "fix it in post" why don't you truncate the description before the table needs to try and fit it into its columns? I did it like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="description">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ 'Parts.description' | translate }} </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                {{(element.description.length > 80) ? ((element.description).slice(0, 80) + '...') : element.description}}
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

So I first check if the array is bigger than a certain length, if Yes then truncate and add '...' otherwise pass the value as is. This enables us to still benefit from the auto-spacing the table does :)

[image]

Comment: Best solution for me as I wanted to truncate data as well. In other solutions if u just provide the width of column the row height gets enlarged as data grows beyond the width

Answer (score 12):

we can add attribute **width**  directly to th

eg:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position" >
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef width ="20%"> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: As of now, width is deprecated to use on TH tag.

Comment: Just to add to the paper trail, the official docs confirm it: [<th>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th#Attributes)

Answer (score 6):

Just need to update the width of the `th` tag.

```css
th {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: That is by far the easiest one to apply, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qIeC.png)I had a table with four columns. Please see the screenshot. In the scss file I had include below code:

```
.full-width-table {
  width: 100%;
}
.mat-column-id {
  width: 15% !important;
}
.mat-column-question {
  width: 55% !important;
}
.mat-column-view {
  width: 15% !important;
}
.mat-column-reply {
  width: 15% !important;
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: This worked for me. You can checkout the attached image

Comment: @AlanObject because you should never use !important in styles, this is a bad practice

Comment: @DilyanDimitrov where is !important used except on styles?

Comment: !important is usually a no-go

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fixedLayout="true"` attribute like `<table #table  mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" fixedLayout="true">`

fixedLayout : Whether to use a fixed table layout. Enabling this option will enforce consistent column widths and optimize rendering sticky styles for native tables. No-op for flex tables.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to give a fixed width to a particular column you can add `fxFlex="60px"` both to `mat-cell` and `mat-header-cell`.

Comment: This is a great solution when you cannot use css because you don't know the names of the columns.

Answer (score 3):

Below Css Class worked in Angular 13.2.3

```
.width-textArea {  
     width: 150px;  
     max-width: 150px;  
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Class needed to be specified in both <th and <Td

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="comments">
          <th class="width-textArea" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="TableHeaderRow">Comments</th>
          <td class="width-textArea" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.comments}} </td>
        </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `style="width:5% !important;"` to **th** and **td**

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
    <th style="width:5% !important;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Full Name </th>
    <td style="width:5% !important;" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.username}} ( {{element.usertype}} )</td>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: There's no need for `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use the CSS selector mat-column-[matColumnDef]. However, if you want to apply CSS to all columns you can use a wildcard attribute selector:

```
[class*="mat-column-"] {
    //your styles here
}
```

This is helpful if you want to apply common styling. Just note that you must use a wildcard and not a caret "^" character (begins with) since there are multiple classes assigned to the class attribute. This also will apply to any element with a class containing "mat-column-".

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this in global css add

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

and in your user.component.css file you add

```
.mat-column-<your-column-name> {
   word-break: break-word;
   width: <width-u-need>% !important;
}
```

works like a charm

Answer (score -1):

Just add the class `full-width-table` at tag table.

e.g.
`<table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource">`