# Fix column width in Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am using Angular material table and trying to fix width for few columns as shown below:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

 <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="myHeader"> No. </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > {{element.email}} </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="myHeader"> Name </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>

</mat-table>
```

In CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.mat-column-email{
  width: 150px;
}
```

I read somewhere that we can fix column width by using this format:

```
.mat-column-matColumnDef(Field name) {
 //CSS
 }
```

But above format does not seem to work no matter what. Can anyone please help me out with what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Not sure if this can help, try once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53023265/7124761

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't worked for me

Comment: You can take reference from these solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020792/how-to-set-width-of-mat-table-column-in-angular

Comment: You can take reference from these solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020792/how-to-set-width-of-mat-table-column-in-angular

Comment: You can take reference from these solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020792/how-to-set-width-of-mat-table-column-in-angular

Comment: I tried all the solutions but nothing worked for me except for below solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After trying lot of things, below solution worked for me:

```
  .mat-column-email{
       max-width: 60px !important;
       min-width: 60px !important;
    }
```

So, instead of setting width, set max-width and min-width of that column.

Comment: Yes `min-width` overrules the table columns