Apply .mat-column-name styles to child component in Angular Material
Child component contains an Angular material table, that is created based on columns passed as input:
<table mat-table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns" [matColumnDef]="col">
</table>

@Input() columns: string[]

Parent component provides columns definitions. However, the only way I can affect f.e. mat table column width is by setting the stylesheet with
.mat-column-col-name {
  width: 10px
}

How can I set mat-column width from the parent component? Names of columns are known by parent, can be defined in it's stylesheet. I strongly want to avoid any encapsulation: none, because child component is inside a library I develop. Passing styles as @Input() would be the best solution.
Edit: I'm also using material themes, which prevents styles outside library from applying, I'd love not to change lib interfaces if possible:
// Library
$theme: map.merge(
  primary: mat.define-palette($my-palette-grey),
  secondary: mat.define-palette($my-palette-blue)
);

// Child in lib
@mixin theme($theme) {
 .my-table-component {

// Parent global css
@use '@my-lib/src/theme' as theme;
@use '@my-lib/table/src/theme/table-component' as table;
@include table.theme($theme);

Therefore:
.wrapper {
  .my-table-component {
    border: 5px solid red; // easily applied, even without !important
    .mat-column-type {
      width: 99em !important; // Never applied


We can use ::ng-deep to make the styles visible from the parent to the children like so
:: ng-deep .mat-column-col-name {
  width: 10px
}

If you are not a fan of ::ng-deep, I would suggest add a class to the parent element that wraps the child .wrapper-class, then going to the angular global styles file either styles.scss or global-styles.scss and applying the styles, this will scope the styles to only this class element and its children, the file will be located on the src folder!
.wrapper-class .mat-column-col-name {
  width: 10px
}

parent:
<div class="wrapper-class">
    <child-component/>
</div>


Thanks, I've considered those 2 similar to using no encapsulation, but the problem is that I'm using material themes for child, so I can't make it work. Is it possible to use the solution with global styles, while keeping material theme implementation? I've edited the comment to show themes.

@JoshThunar you can override it using !important or use specificality, for ex, add classess attrbutes or selector, to increase the CSS priority and finally apply the style!

Thank you, however this solution only allows to edit my own styles, not .mat-column-type. I can easily add stylings to f.e. .my-table, but accessing those inner material classes is not possible from this level, even with !important. It just has no effect.

@JoshThunar please share working example on stackblitz, because its difficult to help you :ng-deep .wrapper-class .mat-column-col-name { width:100% !important }  this should work, need working example to debug!

Thank you, putting my lib into stackblitz was time consuming, but allowed me to extract the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74259086/fix-column-width-in-angular-material-table
I've focused on potential issues with themes, while it was about the specific behavior of mat table column width. It works with max-width !important
